# Simply Search with AngularJS and PHP Web Service

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services, rest

i have tried to create simply search with angularJS comunicate with php web service. check this out this is the interface index.html : 
`

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <p> cek jumlah processor perangkat</p>  
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="form-group">Filter Perangkat : </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="cpu" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control"  />
                            </div>  
                     <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="find(cpu)">Submit</button>
                     </form>
                    </div>
```

the service on app.js :

```
obj.grafik5= function (cpu) {
    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'grafik5?cpu=' + cpu).then(function (status) {
        return status.data;
    });
};
```

then the controller app.js :

```
`app.controller('grafikku', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, services, cpu) {
 $scope.find= function(cpu) {
        $location.path('/grafik');
       services.grafik5(cpu);
      };`
```

and from php side :

```
   private function grafik5()
        {           
            if($this->get_request_method() != "GET")
            {
                $this->response('',406);
            }

            $cpu=(string)$this->_request['cpu'];

                $sql = "Select * FROM data WHERE cpu ="$cpu";
                $r = $this->mysqli->query($sql) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);

                    $success = array("status" => "Success", "msg" => "Successfully one record deleted.");
                    $this->response($this->json($success),200);

        }
```

i have tested on php side with postman, and its working properly. but i know my mistake is on angular side. i really stuck right here. please help me, im new on angular

Answer (score 0):

```
return $http.get(serviceBase + 'grafik5?cpu=' + cpu).then(function (status) {
    return status.data;
});
```

$http.get is asynchronous so at best here I think you'r returning a promise (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

You can try to get the data first :

```
obj.grafik5= function (cpu) {
      return $http.get(serviceBase + 'grafik5?cpu=' + cpu);
};

app.controller('grafikku', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, services, cpu) {
 $scope.find= function(cpu) {
   services.grafik5(cpu).then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
   }), function (error){ 
       console.log(error);
       }
  };
```

Comment: update : hello i forget something, i had an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on this : .when('/grafik', {
  tittle : 'grafik',
  templateUrl: 'grafik/grafik1.php'
  controller:'grafikku'
  })

Comment: you'r missing a comma before controller

Comment: oh my,thanks,back to the top problem, i've tried 
app.controller('grafikku', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $routeParams, services, cpu) {
 $scope.find= function(cpu) {
   services.grafik5(cpu).then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
   }), function (error){ 
       console.log(error);
       }
  }; but there's nothing show on console. there's nothing happen whene i clicking submit button on form. where's the mistake is? thanks before

Comment: Maybe the problem lies with the $http syntax, serviceBase value or something

Comment: yeah i really dont know where's the porblem is, i waste 6hours for this. serviceBase working properly with another function.